A clever way of calculating sum of partial derivatives
Given the function in 4 variables $f(x, y, z, t) = \frac{x - y}{x - t} + \frac{t - x}{y - z}$ prove that $f'_x + f'_y + f'_z + f'_t = 0$.
Of course one can prove this by mechanically carrying out all of the calculations but is there a clever way of doing this which goes around that at least a little?

Is the first term really not supposed to have a $z$ in it?

@ThomasAndrews yes, I just double checked. It is correct.

In general, if $g(x,y)=C(x-y),$ then $g_x+g_y=0.$ And if $h(x,y)=\frac D{x-y}$ then $h_x+h_y=0,$ where $C$ and $D$ are constants. So this shows, if $m(x,y,z,t)=\frac{t-x}{y-z},$ then $m_y+m_z=0$ and $m_t+m_x=0.$ Don't know how to manage the first term, with $x$ in the numerator and denominator. My guess is that it actually isn't true there, and that there is a typo in the question you were given.

More generally, if $p(u)$ is any differentiable function, then $q(x,y)=p(x-y)$ satisfies $q_x+q_y=0.$

Okay, no typo in the question - I've verified it is a solution, I think.
